# intellij-idea remote sharing on Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, localhost, remote-access

I working on iPad application and I'm using intellij idea as IDE.

I would like to see the project on Safari on my iPad but if I try to connect at my ip found in `ifconfig` : `192.168.0.10` it show nothing...

I don't know how does it work on a Mac to see my projects remotely...

Someone know how to do that?

I know how to do it on Windows machines setting up the hosts.txt file, but I cannot find any solution on Google.